# Installing Linux *to* a NFS mount

Tags: linux, installation, nfs

I am about to install Linux (Mint) on a first-generation Eee PC. The device is fully sufficient hardware-wise (as I verified using the "Live" environment), except for one thing: The internal storage (~4GB) is not big enough for a full-blown installation.

That shouldn't matter that much - it wouldn't be the first network-booting system in my home network that relies on my NAS storage for its root filesystem (the first being a Raspberry Pi happily doing its chores).

However, with the Raspberry things were different - I *had* a fully functional installation, which I merely copied over to the NAS, tweaked the bootloader, and there you are.

With the Eee PC, things are differerent. As far as I can see, I would need to *install* to the NAS mount point, right from the start. However, the installer dialog only shows me /dev/sda partitions to chose from, not mount points.

Trying to search the web, I found lots of advice installing *from* NFS, but none for installing *to* NFS. Anyone having an idea?

(Like, wrapping the NFS mount in some way so the installer "sees" it as a block device? Something like that? Or something completely different?)

Comment: Have you considered temporarily putting in a bigger HDD?

Comment: @ekaj: So painfully obvious that I stared at my monitor for a minute trying to figure out why I had been so blind. Especially since I have an empty USB drive sitting right next to me on the desk... turn that into an answer and you get the checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would put a bigger HDD into the computer and install the OS on that - then follow the same method that you did to get the Raspberry Pi to work correctly.

Comment: As I said above, pretty much obvious once I got my mind out of the tight little corner of being hell-bent on using the NFS mount directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. install distro that you want in virtual environment
2. mount NFS to virtual installed linux
3. copy over everything except /boot
4. start eeePC with live distro (same arch x64 or x86)
5. copy /boot from virtual machine to eeePC
6. mount NFS as /
7. cd /
8. chroot .
9. grub-install
10. fix grup config, be sure that you can mount NFS during boot (kernel modul is in place)
11. profit